# Forcing UITableView to render all cells if available

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView in Xamarin iOS and the requirements are this:

There are always at most 10 items to display in a table. There may be less (like 3), but never more than 10.

The Table should always show all 10 rows, and the height should be such that the table never scrolls (because it's only 10 rows).

What would be a good way to make sure it always shows all 10 (or shrinks in height if it's less like 3). This table shares the page with some other elements, so it's not the only thing on the screen. You can scroll on this page.

Right now it's showing the first 5 in the view, but I have to scroll to view the rest. Would this be a matter of me setting the height in StoryBoard to be rather high? But if I do this, would the table shrink automatically if it had a fixed height?

Any advice/recommendations? Again, remember it will only be 10 records, so not a lot to manage in memory. I want to use a UITableView because of the customizations and repetition of the cells, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to (programmatically) set the height of `UITableView` to be the the sum of the height of it's cells.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to change. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you aren't doing it right. Once you set the height of the UITableView, then it will render every cell it can in the space you have given it.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on how to do it? I'm setting it in AwakeFromNib programmatically as   60.0f * totalItems.Count  (which produces the right height) but it still only renders 6 items instead of 10.

Comment: Then I assume that each cell is, in fact, taller than `60.0f` (according to the math you have illustrated, it's likely that each cell is `100.0f`). Try setting it to `100.0f` and see what happens.

Comment: My bad, if you have loaded the tableView before you set the height, then you'll need to reload it.

Comment: So in AwakeFromNib() change the table's Frame with it's height property being higher right? If I just passed 1000 in there that should be enough right?

Comment: I misread your earlier comment, you said **which produces the right height** - so if the height is correct (and you see 6 rows, with a bunch of empty space beneath it where 4 more rows could fit) then you probably just have to reload the data in your tableview to cause the 4 extra rows to be rendered. Note: if you set the height before you set the data on the table view, then you shouldn't need to reload the data in your table view and I have absolutely no idea why you have enough room, but your rows aren't being rendered.

Comment: ah sorry no it's more like there are 6 rows, and no visible room for anything more, but you can scroll the tableview down to see 4 more.

Comment: Then in that case, you should just need to increase `60.0f*totalItems.Count` to `100.0f*totalItems.count`